# Are idealists committed to claiming that every idea contains its inversion?

Tags: existence, idealism

Are idealists - does anyone claim - about some domain - committed to believing that every idea contains its inversion?

So that, e.g. when an effect depends on its cause, the cause also depends on its effect. Or, another example, when something is in the past it is also in the future.

I think it pretty trivial there can be no IDEA of cause without an effect. If reality is just ideas, does that mean the *existence* of a cause depends on its effect?

Comment: probably an awful question, idk. feedback welcome!

Comment: This is not a feature of any idealists I have read.  It is, however, the consequence of using Hume's version of causation, which is only correlation.  Cause and effect are not distinguishable if all they are is correlation.